# Replace spaces at the beginning of line with "-"

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
 wqdq
 wqdqgrhehr
 cnkzjncicoajc
 hello space
    oejwfoiwejfow
    wqodojw
    more spaces
    more
```

This is my file and I would like to make this with `sed`:

```
-wqdq
-wqdqgrhehr
-cnkzjncicoajc
-hello space
----oejwfoiwejfow
----wqodojw
----more spaces
----more
----
-
--
```

Do I have to use loop to make it or does it exist any different approach?
I tried this:

```
user:~$ sed -n  '
: loop
  s/^ /-/
  s/[^-] /-/p
t loop' spaces
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `sed`, you'd need either a loop like:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/^\( *\) /\1-/; t1' < file
```

Or do something like:

```
sed '
s/ */&\
/; # add a newline after the leading spaces
h; # save a copy on the hold space
y/ /-/; # replace *every* space with -
G; # append our saved copy
s/\n.*\n//; # remove the superflous part' < file
```

With `perl`, you can do things like:

```
perl -pe 's{^ *}{$& =~ y/ /-/r}e' < file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/(^|\G) /-/g' < file
```

`\G` in PCRE matches (with zero-width) at the end of the previous match (in `//g` context). So here, we're replacing a space that follows either the beginning of the line `^` or the end of the previous match (that is, the previously substituted space).

(that one would also work with `sed` implementations that support PCREs like `ssed -R`).

With `awk`, you can do something like:

```
awk '
  match($0, /^ +/) {
    space = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)
    gsub(" ", "-", space)
    $0 = space substr($0, RLENGTH+1)
  }
  {print}' < file
```

If you want to convert tabs as well (where for instance `<space><tab>foo` would be converted to `--------foo`), you can preprocess the input with `expand`. With GNU `expand`, you can make it `expand -i` so that only the tabs among the leading blanks in the line are converted. You can specify how far apart the tab-stops are (every 8 columns be default) with the `-t` option.

To generalise that to all horizontal spacing characters, or at least those that are in the `[:blank:]` category in your locale, that becomes more complicated.

If it weren't for the TAB character, it would just be a matter of:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -MText::CharWidth=mbswidth -pe 's/^\h+/"-" x mbswidth($&)/e'
```

But the TAB character being a *control* character has a width of `-1` with that `mbswidth()`, while in reality it *has* a variable width from 1 to 8 columns depending on where it's found on the line.

The `expand` command takes care of expanding it to the *right* number of spaces, but several implementations, including GNU `expand` don't get it right when there are multi-byte characters (like all the blank characters except tab, space in UTF-8 locales), and even some of those that support multi-byte characters can be fooled by zero-width or double-width characters (like U+3000 which is in the `[:blank:]` class in typical GNU locales at least). So one would have to do the TAB expansion by hand like:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -MText::CharWidth=mbswidth -pe 's{^\h+}{
  $s = $&;
  while ($s =~ /(.*?)\t(.*)/) {
    $s = $1 . (" " x ((7-mbswidth($1)) % 8 + 1)) . $2;
  }
  "-" x mbswidth($s)}e'
```

Comment: I think that `perl -pe 's/^([ ]+)/"-" x length $1/e'` conveys intent a little better when it comes to a perl solution.

Comment: @hobbs. That works too. That's _replace the sequence of spaces at the beginning with as many "-"s as there were characters in that sequence of blanks_ (I don't find using a capture group instead of `$&` helps with legibility though). I find that the `s{^ *}{$& =~ tr/ /-/r}e` (_replace the sequence of spaces at the beginning with itself after translation of space -> "-"_) is a more direct translation of the requirements though.

Answer (score 0):

Stephane has already provided the proper `sed` solution. Here's a small and a little more explicit Python 3 alternative:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        beginning = True
        for char in line:
            if beginning and char == " ":
                print("-",end="")
            else:
               beginning = False
               print(char,end="")
```

Test run:

```
# This is the input text
$ cat -A input.txt
 wqdq$
 wqdqgrhehr$
 cnkzjncicoajc$
 hello space$
    oejwfoiwejfow$
    wqodojw$
    more spaces$
    more$
    $
 $
  $

# And this is the output with the given python script
$ ./add_dashes.py ./input.txt                                                                                            
-wqdq
-wqdqgrhehr
-cnkzjncicoajc
-hello space
----oejwfoiwejfow
----wqodojw
----more spaces
----more
----
-
--
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Working

We setup a `do-while` loop and keep converting the last space adjacent to the first non-space while the line still has a leading space.

```
sed -e '
   :loop
      /^ /s/ \([^ ]\|$\)/-\1/
   tloop
' filename.ext


while IFS= read -r l; do
   read -r ll <<<"$(printf '%ss\n' "$l")"
   printf '%s%s\n' \
      "$(seq -s= 0 "$(expr "$l" : '[   ]*')" | tr = - | tr -cd -)" \
      "${ll%?}"
done < filename.ext
```

---

### Result

```
-wqdq
-wqdqgrhehr
-cnkzjncicoajc
-hello space
----oejwfoiwejfow
----wqodojw
----more spaces
----more
----
-
--
```

---

### Workings

- Setup a `while` loop to read the file line-by-line with an `IFS` set to `NULL`. This has the purpose of preserving all whitespace in the line.
- Next do a dummy read of the same line with the default `IFS`. This will clip any leading whitespace. We add a dummy nonnewline char at the end to prevent collapse of the trailing newlines in command expansion stage. We strip it away at the time of printing.
- The `expr` command has the purpose of finding the number of matches, in our case, whitespace at the leading edge of the line.
- Using this number we generate a seqence of dashes by means of `seq` and `tr` commands appropriately setup.
- Finally we print the dashes alongwith the `trimmed` line, i.e., line read in via the default IFS.

Comment: [That is running 8 commands **for each line** of the input, where you could have done it with one command for the whole input](/q/169716). The second `read` command also trims trailing space and tabs (assuming a default value of `$IFS`).

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach:

```
awk 'match($0, /^[[:space:]]+/){ p=""; l=RLENGTH; while(l--) p=p"-";
     sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,p); print}' yourfile
```

The output:

```
-wqdq
-wqdqgrhehr
-cnkzjncicoajc
-hello space
----oejwfoiwejfow
----wqodojw
----more spaces
----more
----
-
--
```

---

`match($0, /^[[:space:]]+/)` - matches sequence of leading spaces

`l=RLENGTH` - the size of the matched sequence for each line

`while(l--) p=p"-"` - constructing the replacement substring

---

---

Alternative ***Python*** 3.x approach:

***space_to_hyphen.py*** script:

```
import sys, re
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:  # reading input file
    for l in f.read().splitlines():
        m = re.match(r'^ +', l)    # capture sequence of leading spaces 
        print(l if not m else l.replace(' ', '-', m.end()))
```

***Usage***:

```
python3 space_to_hyphen.py yourfile
```

Comment: It's use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[[:space:]]`. With `[[:space:]]`, you'd convert the CR of blank lines of MSDOS formatted text files (`[[:space:]]` is horizontal or vertical spaces, `[[:blank:]]` is horizontal only).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, feel free to upvote my answer

Comment: Note that even after s/space/blank/, that would still convert TAB or `"　"` (U+3000) to a _single_ dash, changing the displayed width of the line (which may or may not be desired, I'm just pointing it out)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, there's no `s/space/blank/` within my approaches as you noted. And they work fine for the current input

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant that even if you replaced `[[:space:]]` with `[[:blank:]]` (as I'm not sure replacing vertical spacing characters make sense here), that might not do what people want for characters like TAB or U+3000 that are not single-width characters (but are matched by `[[:blank:]]` and `[[:space:]]` in some locales). The OP's sample has only ASCII SPC characters, so it won't make any difference whether one uses `" "`, `[[:space:]]`, `[[:blank:]]` (or even `[^[:print:]]`), I'm just flagging it as a _note_ for people coming here with a similar requirement.